# Why does SwaggerHub return error 403 when I test my OpenAPI definition?

Tags: openapi, swaggerhub

I have the following OpenAPI definition hosted on SwaggerHub:
https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/MyFirstAPI/1.0.1-oas3

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
servers:
  - url: http://api.myfirstapi.com/
info:
  version: 1.0.1-oas3
  title: Equ API
paths:
  /query:
    get:
      tags:
        - developers
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: searchString
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: search results matching criteria
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Equity'
        '400':
          description: There is 400
components:
  schemas:
    Equity:
      ...
```

When I test the `GET /query` request, it returns a 403 error:

```
content-length: 0 
date: Fri,10 Sep 2021 14:32:54 GMT 
server: nginx/1.18.0 + Phusion Passenger(R) 6.0.8 
status: 403 Forbidden 
via: 1.1 b5d86079363e9709b4c4051d3c94ac3d.cloudfront.net (CloudFront) 
x-amz-cf-id: pYbLwlrEHg5DXkGe5FkysAjSjbSDqUg7Rrhbv-Dt8Xwt8JuPRMAW3Q== 
x-amz-cf-pop: DEL54-C1 
x-cache: Error from cloudfront 
x-powered-by: Express,Phusion Passenger(R) 6.0.8
```

Why does this error happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Need more details. What tool do you use to test the request - Swagger UI, Postman, something else? If the API you're testing is public - please add the request URL and parameters in your question. 403 response indicates a permission error - did you include the proper authentication info in the request?

Answer (score 0):

This 403 error is somewhat misleading. The actual problem here is that the target server for requests - `api.myfirstapi.com` - does not actually exist. The `servers` list is supposed to specify your real server(s).

If you are designing a new API and don't have a live server yet, you can use SwaggerHub's [mock server](https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/integrations/api-auto-mocking.html) to similate responses and test API calls.

To add a mock to your API definition:

1. Click the API name on the editor toolbar.
2. Switch to the **Integrations** tab and click **Add New Integrations**.
   [image: SwaggerHub: Adding a new API-level integration]
3. Select **API Auto Mocking** from the list and click **Add**.
4. Enter any value for **Name** (e.g. *mock*), leave other options as is, and click **Create and Execute**.
5. Close the remaining dialogs.

This creates a mock server for your API and adds it to the `servers` list in your API definition:

```yaml
servers: 
  - description: SwaggerHub API Auto Mocking
    url: https://virtserver.swaggerhub.com/OWNER_NAME/API_NAME/VERSION
```

Make sure to select this server in the API docs before you test API calls.

[image: SwaggerHub mock server in the Servers list in interactive API docs]